# How to download text file in Spring Framework while retrieving it from database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream, java-stream

I want to create a very large text file on the fly from a database and download it while data is still being retrieved from the database so that the user won't wait several minutes for the data being prepared to start the download process.

I thought that Java had only one type of Stream but it looks like it has dozens so this one didn't work:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/export/testdownload"}, produces = "text/csv")
@ApiOperation(value = "Test downloading")
public ResponseEntity testDownloading() {
    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .body(IntStream.range(0, 5).mapToObj(i -> getData(i, 10)));
}

public Integer getData(Integer page, Integer perPage) {
    return page * perPage;
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/export/testdownload"}, produces = "text/csv")
@ApiOperation(value = "Test downloading")
public ResponseEntity testDownloading() {
    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .body(SomeKindOfStream.range(0, 5).mapToObj(i -> getData(i, 10)));
}

public String getData(Integer page, Integer perPage) throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    return "test,line," + page + "\n";
}
```

I can retrieve strings from database and output it at once but I don't know how to output those strings continuously while still retrieving. In PHP it is easy, just echo the string within the loop but in Java I think I need to convert the string into some kind of Stream and then use some kind of pipe.

Comment: Did you take a look on Project Reactor and reactive Spring? One can create non-blocking operations with Spring Boot only but there is no easy way to create non-blocking endpoints.